# Highcharts stacked columns based on each day value

Tags: highcharts, stacked-chart, column-chart

i'm trying to make a stacked column chart based on the following values

```
[

  {
    "date": "2019-06-08",
    "profileId": "2978",
    "likes": "48",
    "source": "text",
    "brand": "Pepsi",
    "comments": "8",
    "followers": "23443",
    "ER": "1.00439"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-06-10",
    "profileId": "6456",
    "likes": "93",
    "source": "media",
    "brand": "pepsi",
    "comments": "3",
    "followers": "54482",
    "ER": "0.99969"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-06-10",
    "profileId": "6215",
    "likes": "457",
    "source": "media",
    "brand": "pepsi",
    "comments": "11",
    "followers": "233113",
    "ER": "1.00818"
  }
]
```

and here's the chart object

```
const brandsValueChartOptions = {
      chart: {
        type: 'column',
      }
      credits: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Date',
        },
        categories: brandsValue.x,
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return moment(this.value).format('Do MMM')
          },
        },
        crosshair: true,
        grouping: true
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Value (in USD)',
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span>',
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0,
          stacking: 'normal',
          },
        },
        series: {
          stacking: 'true'
      }
      },
      series: brandsValue.y,
    }
```

and here how i process the data on the structure the results object to be used in the chart object above.

```
    const brandsValue = {
     x: [],
    y: [],
  }
  let colorIndex = 0

  _.chain(data)
    .map(brand => {
      return {
        ...brand,
        day: brand.date,
        brand: _.capitalize(brand.brand.toLowerCase()),
      }
    })
    .forEach(brand => brandsValue.x.push(brand.day))
    .groupBy(brand => brand.brand)
    .forEach(items => {
      if (values.mediaTypeSelected === 'posts') {
        items.forEach(item => {
          let followersCount = parseInt(item.followers)
          let er = parseFloat(item.ER)
          item.finalCost =  100 * er
          item.date = new Date(item.date).getTime()
          return item
        })
      }
    })
    .forEach(item => {
      let sorted = _.sortBy(item, i => moment(i.date))
      let values = {
        name: item[0].brand,
        color: "#cccccc",
        data: [],
      }

      sorted.forEach(i => {
        if (this.state.mediaTypeSelected === 'posts') {
          values.data.push([
            moment(i.date).format('Do MMM'),
            parseInt(i.finalCost),
            i.profileId,
          ])
        }
      })

      brandsValue.y.push(values)
    })
    .value()
```

The problem here, is that the x-axis values aren't grouped/stacked based on the date, i've tried several solutions with no luck,
here's how the chart results looks like
[image]

Comment: Hi @M1M6, Please try to change `xAxis.categories: brandsValue.x` to `xAxis.type: 'category`. If that does not help, please provide me with a part of your data after preprocess.

Comment: Hey @ppotaczek thanks for ur response, it seems like they are grouped now, but invalid x-axis date appear, also any stacked bar doesn't give a correct values on hover, mostly there's some configurations should be done for the graph, however here's the results after preprocessing

Comment: https://justpaste.it/6gb94

Comment: actually it help, i removed duplicate date processing, also added a stacked property for the columns, and it's working now, thanks @ppotaczek for helping!